# What should I do with local player when invite accepted? (Game Center)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm making my first iPhone multiplayer game using Game Center. I have setup so everything is working expect the invitations. I have come so far that when I receive an invitations and accept it, the player who accepted names comes up on the other device. But, on the device that accepted the invite nothing is happening. What am i'm supposed to do? I'm looking for some method like "localPlayerDidAcceptInvite".

```
   - (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didAcceptInvite:(GKInvite *)invite {
        // Called when another player accepts a match invite from the local player.

        NSLog(@"[GCManager] didAcceptInvite:");

    //if ([self.multiplayerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gameCenterManager:match:didAcceptMatchInvitation:player:)])
        [self.multiplayerDelegate gameCenterManager:self match:self.multiplayerMatch didAcceptMatchInvitation:invite player:player];
}

    - (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didRequestMatchWithPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDsToInvite {
        // Called when the local player starts a match with another player from Game Center.
        // When this method is called, the game is launched from Game Center and starts the matchmaking process.

        NSLog(@"[GCManager] didRequestMatchWithPlayers:");

        if ([self.multiplayerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gameCenterManager:match:didRecieveMatchInvitationForPlayer:playersToInvite:)])
            [self.multiplayerDelegate gameCenterManager:self match:self.multiplayerMatch didRecieveMatchInvitationForPlayer:player playersToInvite:playerIDsToInvite];
    }
```